# Defined Variable inside scope undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This is defined in  tags in the dom on SOME pages.

```
var client_mail = 'me@example.com';
```

Then this is called in a js file so that if the above variable is not defined, it gets it from a known field input.

```
$(document).on("modal-loaded", function() {
    if (!client_mail) {
        var client_mail = $('#edit-field-email .form-text').val();
    }
    $('#client_mail').val(client_mail);
});
```

On the pages where the global IS defined, the above works and I see the email inside the #client_email textfield.

On the pages where the global IS NOT defined, I get [object HTMLInputElement] in the textfield.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: In the second case you're logging `client_mail` before the `"modal-loaded"` event fires. Move the log command inside the callback function. JS is event-based; most code does not run top to bottom.

Comment: well `var client_mail` is defined inside of a block scope that is not global AND it is called asynchronously.... So it is not going to work

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake when writing the question, the console.log is inside the modal event - edited the question

Comment: After the edit, the question I have is if what does `$('#edit-field-email input').val()` return?

Comment: It comes back with an element "<input name="email" class="form-text" type="email" id="client_mail" value="" required="">"

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: It shows the whole element in the console - and prints [object HTMLInputElement] if I try and use the var on the page

Comment: The console is not the same thing as when that code is executed.  Put `console.log($('#edit-field-email input').val())` inside your event handler and see what it logs, when it actually runs

Comment: Can you please make sure that the code in the question is the one you're actually  using...? Nowhere in there are you logging an input element.

Comment: Sure thing, Ive updated the question.

Comment: OK - the biggest difference is the "var" before the "client_mail" in the modal event. Adding or removing that makes it work on either page, but not both

Comment: Ok. The main problem here is that the `var client_mail` declaration in your function gets hoisted to the top and shadows the outer `client_mail`. Which means that `if (!client_mail)` checks out regardless of whether it's defined outside or not, becaue the inner one is *always* undefined at that point.

Comment: Ahh. So when you call the var again, even if its inside the IF funtion, its going to override it? Is that asyncronous then? I was excpecting it to cascade

Comment: Even weirder - if remove all that code, and just call console.log(client_mail); on both pages. Where the var is set, i get the email... but where it isnt set, it returns a whole element with a matching ID. Does console.log(client_mail); target an ID?

Comment: Yes, I was stumped by this but that's exactly what happens: setting an `id` for an element allows you to access it directly in your code. Which means if the mail address isn't predefined, `$('#client_mail').val(client_mail);` sets the value of the `HTMLInputElement` to a textual representation of itself.

Comment: very odd! ok thank you, I will try and find a way around it!

Comment: Just use a different `id` for the field you're trying to set.

Comment: Ive done exactly that and its worked. Thanks!